# ForegroundService, Notification и выход из спящего режима

Tags: java, android, service, уведомления, pendingintent

Проблема в следующем: я создал сервис

```
  @Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    System.out.println("Service: onStartCommand");
    Log("Service: onStartCommand");

    String CHANNEL_ID = "_01";
    if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
        NotificationChannel channel = null;
        channel = new NotificationChannel(CHANNEL_ID,
                "Notification channel",
                NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_DEFAULT);


    ((NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE)).createNotificationChannel(channel);
}

    intent = new Intent(this,MainActivity_Large.class);
    //                         intent.setAction(STATE_START);
    //      intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT);
 //   intent.addFlags(//Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP |
          //  Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP |
 //           Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, intent,  PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

    NotificationCompat.Builder builder =
            new NotificationCompat.Builder(this,CHANNEL_ID)
                    .setVisibility(NotificationCompat.VISIBILITY_PUBLIC)
                    .setAutoCancel(true)
                    .setChannelId(CHANNEL_ID)
                    .setDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_ALL)
                    .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.intro)
                    //                                     .setLargeIcon(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(context.getResources(), R.drawable.kr_red_30x30))
                    .setContentTitle("")
                    .setContentText("")
                    .setSound(RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION))
                    .setPriority(2)
                    .setContentIntent(pendingIntent);

    notification = builder.build();
    startForeground(1, notification);

    return START_STICKY;
}
```

запускаю его вот так в onCreat():

```
        intent1=new Intent(this, MyService.class);

        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
           this.startForegroundService(intent1);
        }else {
           startService(intent1);
        }
```

После засыпания и просыпания устройства, на экране отображается уведомление, что приложение работает. Два раза тапнув по нему я перехожу в само приложение, но при этом в логе я вижу следующее:

```
onRestart
onStart
onResume
onPause
onSaveInstanceState
onStop
onRestart
onStart
onResume
```

т.е. получается, что приложение запустилось, затем остановилось и следом опять запустилось. Я пробовал разные флаги выставлять у Notification, но каждый раз одно и тоже, либо совсем не, то что нужно.

Comment: наверное не приложение а активность, не понятно что вам нужно, в чем вопрос

Comment: Да, активность. Вопрос: почему она запускается дважды? Вместе с этим и весь код дублируется.

Comment: Собственно а почему нет? Хоть трижды. Система захотела.

Comment: Ну, может и так. Только система получается тогда не совсем предсказуемая. Не по програмистски как-то;(

Comment: Ну почему же, система предсказуема, но нужно принимать ее правила. Есть жизненный цикл активности, вот от нее и пляшите.

Comment: Ладно, если исходить из этого, то придётся свою логику допиливать. Спасибо). Хотя меня всё же гложет сомнение, что дело где-то во флагах.

Comment: Например на Android 7 всё как надо исполняется, а на Android 8.1 активити запускается дважды. Очевидно, что это связано с тем, что на 8.1 система обязывает запускать foregroundservice.

Comment: Если система не удалила вашу активность а вне хотите делать вторую копию, установите в манифесте активности android:launchMode="singleTask" , еще в PendingIntent нужно "засовывать" активность с флагом Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK  - строго во избежание ошибок.

Comment: Нет. Без изменений. Ещё выяснилось, что нужно пермишн прописывать: <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.FOREGROUND_SERVICE" />, но тоже не то.

Comment: Вы лучше напишите что делаете и что хотите. startForeground я устанавливаю в onCreate сервиса

Comment: Я хочу, что бы код который в onStart() находится, выполнялся как положено, только один раз. startForeground у меня в onStartCommand это сути не меняет (пробовал).

Comment: перенесите код в onCreate, все равно сложно что-то рекомендовать не зная что вы делаете. Активность и сервис должны "жить своей жизнью" обмениваясь при необходимости широковещательными сообщениями - такова одна из концепций

Comment: зачем вы из службы запускаете активити, а из активити снова службу?

Comment: Это не моя прихоть. На новых устройствах система обязывает выдавать уведомление, что сервис работает в фоне.

Comment: Спасибо за внимание. Вопрос был решён на англоязычной стороне. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68045541/pendingintent-completion/68058733#68058733

Comment: Если вкратце, то в активити нужно переопределить метод `onNewIntent()`. Он вызывается каждый раз при тапе на уведомлении.